# I need import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets(1.6); for java 1.5

Tags: java

I am doing a service with old version the RestTemplate and I have to force the headers:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
```

**This code runs in local**, however, when I uploaded the code a INT:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
...
cannot find symbol
symbol  : class StandardCharsets
location: package java.nio.charset
```

I discovered that StandardCharsets is java 1.6 or more and INT is 1.5 ...
[image]

I searched in google but I can't find the solution.
I need set header with UTF-8 ( to force ) in java 1.5.

Any idea?
Ty !

Comment: So why not simply create the charset manually?

Comment: How do I see the source code? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html. Sorry I am junior...

Comment: How about just using `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`?

Comment: @VGR I used headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "json", Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); But I losed "Ñ" in my database...

Comment: I found the solution: headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");